# Track Number of Guesses for Word Guessing Game

Tags: python

I want to allow the users a maximum attempt of 6 to guess the correct word. Whenever I test run it and put in the correct word, it runs the else statement. I think I'm missing something simple but I can't figure it out.

```
ATTEMPTS = 6
count = 0
word = "abets"
guess = ""
while count < ATTEMPTS:
    guess = input("Guess the word: ").lower
    if guess == word:
        print("Congrats!")
        count += 1
    else:
        print("Oops!")
        count += 1
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

You were missing `()` for the `.lower()` and I added this `and guess != word`to the while loop so that it stops after guessing the word.

```
ATTEMPTS = 6
count = 0
word = "abets"
guess = ""
while count < ATTEMPTS and guess != word:
    guess = input("Guess the word: ").lower()
    if guess == word:
        print("Congrats!")
        count += 1
    else:
        print("Oops!")
        count += 1
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

`lower()` is a function, not a property. Call the function to make it work.

### Code:

```
ATTEMPTS = 6
count = 0
word = "abets"
while count < ATTEMPTS:
    guess = input("Guess the word: ").lower()
    print(guess)
    print(word)
    if guess == word:
        print("Congrats!")
        count += 1
    else:
        print("Oops!")
        count += 1
    print(count)
```

### Output:

```
Guess the word: abets
abets
abets
Congrats!
1
```

### Output without lower as a function:

```
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x000001EAEAF88CF0>
abets
Oops!
1
```